# On dense embedding of Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Disclaimer:** When I came up with this question yesterday, I suspected it to be trivial (trivially true or trivially false). Then it kept me awake several hours tonight... (I still hope, though, this is just due to my ignorance.)

**Question.** Let $E,F$ be Banach space and suppose that $E$ embeds densely and continuously into $F$ (so we consider $E$ as a subspace of $F$ from now on). Assume that there exists a constant $M \in (0,\infty)$ with the following property:

For each $f \in F$ we can find a sequence $(e_n)$ in $E$ that converges to $f$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_F$ and that satisfies $\|e_n\|_E \le M \|f\|_F$.

Does it follow that $E = F$?

**Remark.** I first thought the answer should be yes due to some application of the open mapping theorem: clearly, it suffices to show that $\|\cdot\|_E$ and $\|\cdot\|_F$ are equivalent on $E$, and by the open mapping theorem this is true iff $\|\cdot\|_F$ is complete on $E$; but I wasn't able to prove that latter property.

Am I overlooking some simple argument, or a simple counterexample?

**Edit.** It is probably worthwhile to note the following fact:

As observed by Nate Eldredge in a (now deleted) comment, it is easy to see that the answer is "yes" if $E$ is reflexive: Given $f \in F$ and $(e_n) \subseteq E$ as above, we can choose a subsequence of $(e_n)$ that converges weakly (in $E$) to a vector $e \in E$. For each $f' \in F'$ this implies that $\langle f', f\rangle = \langle f', e\rangle$, so $f = e \in E$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great question! What you need is Sandy Grabiner's approximation lemma:

**Lemma**: *Let $E$ and $F$ be Banach spaces, let $T \in B(E,F)$, and let $M > 0$ and $0 < r < 1$. Suppose that for each $y \in [F]_1$ there exists $x_0 \in [E]_M$ with $\|y - Tx_0\| \leq r$. Then for each $y \in F$ there exists $x \in E$ with $\|x\| \leq \frac{M\|y\|}{1-r}$ and $Tx = y$.*

I think this immediately implies that $F = E$ in your question. You can probably prove the lemma yourself very easily (hint: geometric series), but for the sake of completeness a reference is: Theorem 3.35 of my book *Measure Theory and Functional Analysis*.

It's a great lemma and deserves to be better known. For instance, both the open mapping theorem and Tietze's extension theorem follow easily from it.

Comment: Ha! Thanks a lot, you just saved my day! I thought I'd loose my mind...

Comment: @NateEldredge: Well, you should probably blame this on me. I actually had the feeling it might be a better idea to assume that $E$ embeds into $F$ (for alphabetic reasons) - but for some reason, in my imagination it is always $F$ that embed into $E$... I'll edit my question so that the notation is in agreement with the answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I didn't notice that, fixed.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: you are welcome!

Comment: Aargh, switched them back.

Comment: Probably it was when I was a graduate student when I first saw what is called the "little open mapping theorem".  It says that if $T$ is in $L(X,Y)$ and the closure of $T\mathring{B}_X(1)$ contains $\mathring{B}_Y(r)$, then $T\mathring{B}_X(1)$ contains $\mathring{B}_Y(r)$. The first step is of course the proof of what you call Sandy's approximation lemma. The open mapping theorem is an immediate consequence of the LOMT. A non linear version of this was useful when I was working on  Lipschitz quotient mappings $20+$ years ago. After proving the LOMT in class, an easy HW problem is...

Comment: "Every separable Banach space is isometrically isomorphic to a quotient of $\ell_1$."

Comment: There is a version for complete metric groups of this lemma in Tougeron's book *Ideaux de Fonctions Differentiables* which I can't check now because of Corona.

Answer (score 2):

After Nik Weaver answered the question and Bill Johnson pointed out in a comment that what one needs is actually a part of the usual proof of the open mapping theorem, I thought about it once again, and I think it is worthwhile to explicitly remark that the following more general assertion is true:

**Theorem.** Let $E$, $F$ be Banach space and suppose that $E$ embeds densely and continuously into $F$ (so we may consider $E$ as a subspace of $F$). Suppose that for each $f \in F$ there exists a sequence $(e_n)$ in $E$ which converges to $f$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_F$ and which is bounded with respect to $\|\cdot\|_E$. Then $E = F$.

**Discussion.** The point here is that, in constrast to the statement in the original question, we do not assume a priori that the bound $\sup_n \|e_n\|_E$ is uniform with respect to $\|f\|_F$.

**Proof.** Actually, this is almost exactly the proof of the open mapping theorem, but with a (very) small additional perturbation argument. The details are as follows:

Let $j$ denote the embedding of $E$ into $F$. Let $B_E(e,r)$ denote the open ball in $E$ with radius $r$ and center $e$, and likewise for $F$. It follows from the assumption that
$$
  \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{ j B_E(0,n)}^F = F.
$$
Due to Baire's theorem we can thus find an integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\overline{ j B_E(0,n)}^F$ has non-empty interior in $F$, i.e. it contains a ball $B_F(f,\varepsilon)$.

Since $j(E)$ is dense in $F$, we can choose $e \in E$ such that $j(e)$ is closer than $\varepsilon / 2$ to $f$ (with respect to $\|\cdot\|_F$). (This is the "perturbation argument" mentioned above - well, "argument" is quite an exaggeration...) Hence,
$$
  \overline{ j B_E(0,n)}^F \supseteq B_F(f,\varepsilon) \supseteq B_F(j(e), \varepsilon/2).
$$
Now, we proceed again as in the proof of the open mapping theorem: We can write each $x \in B_F(0, \varepsilon/2)$ as $x = (x+j(e)) - j(e)$, and the vector in brackets is in $B_F(j(e), \varepsilon/2)$ and can thus be approximated (wrt $\|\cdot\|_F$) by a sequence $(j(e_k))$ with $\|e_k\|_E < n$. Since $j(e_k - e)$ approximates $x$ (wrt $\|\cdot\|_F$), we obtain $x \in \overline{ j B_E(0,n + \|e\|)}^F$.

We proved that the $F$-closure of $j B_E(0,n + \|e\|)$  contains $B_F(0, \varepsilon/2)$, so it follows from the small open mapping theorem (see Bill Johnson's comment to Nik Weaver's answer) that $j B_E(0,n + \|e\|)$ itself contains an open ball in $F$ centred at $0$. Hence, $j(E) = F$.

**Edit 2023-05-02.** I found a reference where the theorem above along with
a different proof is explicitly stated: Theorem 5 in "Evgeniĭ A. Lifshits: *Ideally convex sets* (1970)" [(link to zbMATH)](https://zbmath.org/0244.46020)